Azure synapse "Content of directory on path '.../_delta_log/*.*' cannot be listed
I have created a stored procedure when I run it manually:
 EXEC createSQLServerlessView_gold_SalesOrderDetail; inside develop-> SQL script it works fine.
But When I do integration-> pipeline -> stored procedure and choose the same procedure and then run it, it gives me this error:  "Content of directory on path '.../_delta_log/*.*' cannot be listed.
here is Sp script:
USE gold_db_demoGO

CREATE OR ALTER PROC createSQLServerlessView_gold_SalesOrderDetail
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @sql = N'CREATE OR ALTER VIEW SalesOrderDetail AS
        SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
            BULK ''https://destoragedemo2.dfs.core.windows.net/gold/SalesLT/SalesOrderDetail/'',
            FORMAT = ''DELTA''
        ) AS [result]'

    print @sql

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END
GO



Solution
work around is create a group in Microsoft Entra ID, grant it contributor role and add the the current user as a member.

provide the stored procedure sql script you created

Just added the SP script

I solved it by created a group in Micrsoft Entra ID, granted it contributor access and add myself to the group.

The error is because of permission for your managed identity.
I also got same error.

Later i given Storage Blob Data Contributor role for managed identity on the storage account where your files present, check managed identity in you linkedservice to give permission.

Then executed successfully.
.
If you use dedicated pool then you can create credentials in sql server
check this stack solution for more about it.
UPDATE.
Check the access like below in your storage account whether your synapse workspace managed identity present or not.


I already had granted Storage Blob Data Contributor role. It doesn't explain why it can run as SQL script but not in Pipeline in a same synapse workspace

I believe you given role for Microsoft Entra user. or you given to managed identiy? becuase when running sql script you need to give role for the user id you logged in but when it comes to pipeline execution you need to give role to managed identity.

This error is because of permission issue to storage account or where the files present. so, check it once again.

the synapse app has already role as storage blob data contributor

Can you please provide the screenshot like how I given for your storage account destoragedemo2. Meanwhile i will check possible reasons for this error.

Please take a look of the screenshots

Ok you are using linked service for sql database. try with synapse analytics workspace

Sorry, I don't understand this one, I am inside synapse analytic workspace, I need to link to a SQL database which is not in the same workspace.

You are using serverless pool in synapse right?

Yes, serverless db is in Synapse.  I dont know what i missed earlier, but I solved it by created a group in Micrsoft Entra ID, granted it contributor access and add myself to the group.

Please add that as an answer so that it will help community to find better ans.
